# Why this callback does not access the correct value of outer scope?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Using node-mysql I have the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    connection.query('select 1', function(err, rows) {
        console.log('#' + i);
    });
}
```

I expected the result to be #0, #1, ..., #9 but the actual result is #10 printed 10 times. It is obvious it is printing the value of `i` at the moment of the callback's execution instead of the callback creation. How can I implement my desired result?

Comment: `for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) (function(i){connection.query('select 1', function(err, rows){console.log('#' + i)})})(i);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare i with let:

var i   =>  let i

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Comment: Can you explain why this makes a difference?

Comment: The difference is scoping. var is scoped to the nearest function block and let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block, which can be smaller than a function block. Both are global if outside any block.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable

Comment: That won't actually help; you still only have one variable.

Comment: But with let it only scopes the loop block. So I think it is what he was looking for

Comment: @SLaks: JS defines `let` variables declared in the head of a `for` statement, in the loop's body. There's no intermediate scope created, like you'd find in some languages.